# Difference when executing linux command from terminal and java runtime process

Tags: java, shell

I'm looking a way to write running log of python which is executed by java app via script.

Let's say my script is:

```
import time

for x in range(120):
  print("Running ", x)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Here is my current solution:

1. Trigger script using `java`

```
String cmd = "python script.py";
var process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, new File(sandboxPath));
```

2. Write log to new file:

```
String traceLogCmd = String.format("strace -p %s -s 9999 -e trace=write -o output.txt", process.pid());
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(traceLogCmd, null, new File(sandboxPath));
```

Now the problem is `output.txt` only has content whenever the python script is done executing so that I cannot `tailf` the output file.

Meanwhile if I execute `python script.py` and `strace` command dirrectly from terminal, the output is exactly what I expected.

Can someone correct me if I did something wrong or have a another way to get python log?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec()`. More details: [When Runtime.exec() won't](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)

The following code will append to `StringBuilder` object output of the script `sb.append(line);`. It would not be difficult to write that content to a file.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", "python", "path-to-your-script").start();
String result = getCommandResult(p.getInputStream());

private static String getCommandResult(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stream);
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Tried this and replace `sb.append(line)` by `log.info(line)` but nothing was logged

Comment: See my updated post. For test purposes, please print to console `line`. If code is in while loop, there has to be something read.

Comment: Seem like it not even in while loop. I log a random string in the beginning of while loop but it's not printed out